# Python: MySQL DELETE issues

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am trying to delete a value from a table with 2 columns; `twitch` and `name`.

This is the code:

```
cur2 = db.cursor()
cur2.execute("SELECT twitch FROM Alan45wmzYGCc5C7TIMCdczrel.whitelist WHERE twitch NOT IN(SELECT twitch FROM Alan45wmzYGCc5C7TIMCdczrel.followers)")
result = cur2.fetchall()
db.commit()

for row in result:
    unfollowers.extend(row[0])
    unfollowers_join = '\n'.join(unfollowers)
    print unfollowers_join

cur3 = db.cursor()
for x in follows:
    cur3.execute("DELETE FROM Alan45wmzYGCc5C7TIMCdczrel.whitelist WHERE twitch = (%s);", (x,))
data_unfollower = (unfollowers_join)
db.commit()
```

The `result` is the value needing to be deleted, and the `result` is the `cur2` query to find unmatched values.

Comment: Where are you getting the variable 'follows' in your for loop? Also, is there a reason you can't do this in a single sql statement, like: `DELETE FROM Alan45wmzYGCc5C7TIMCdczrel.whitelist WHERE twitch NOT IN(SELECT twitch FROM Alan45wmzYGCc5C7TIMCdczrel.followers)`?

Comment: @MattT Indeed i could have done that! I am new to MySQL and didn't think of joining them like that! Thanks for the help, it it all working now